# i am trying to connect the database in PHP 5, it connects fine with Test named DB, but it doesn't with different named DB

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, localhost

I am trying to connect the database in PHP, I have a database with the name of TEST it connects successfully but when I connect with different named database it does not. I am using PHP 5, Syntax is following

```
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "$user_name", "$password") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

mysqli_select_db($connection,"$db_name") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to DB <br />";

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the error message? maybe the db user has no permission to use the second database

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of mysql permissions?

Maybe you created a mysql user, wich can connect only to 'test' database?

This is a tutorial about mysql users and permissions.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

Comment: thanks, it was the problem of permission, its now solved from user tabs.